# Viewport not syncing with UV image editor when unwrapping an object

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view, uv-image-editor

I am doing an unwrap and for some reason every manipulation that I do in the UV window doesn't update in the viewport right away. I have to click in the viewport, to get it to update. This has happened before but I can't remember how I solved it before. I closed Blender and started it up again, tried updating to the latest version too. Still doesn't sync correctly.

Here's an image of my UV window in case someone can spot something I missed.

[image: UV image editor]

Comment: Precision: I am using Cycles render.

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question in case it happens to someone else, it was a really stupid thing that I overlooked: the ''Update other affected windows'' was locked.
[image]

Comment: In this situation one more thing to check may be option *View* > *Update Automatically*, it will have similar effect, but not affecting *any* action in UV / Image Editor.